# what does / (Divison) operator do in numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

i am new to data science .I have been learning about numpy library in python.But i don't know what division operator do on numpy array

---

```
import numpy as np;
x=np.array([3.4,4.08]);
y=np.array([1.5,1.8]);
print(x/y);
z=np.sum(x/y);
print(z);
```

its output is

[ 2.26666667  2.26666667]

4.53333333333

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/1.17/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html#numpy.divide

Comment: By the way, you don't need to use semicolons in Python

Comment: Like addition and multiplication, it is element-wise, `[3.4/1.5, 4.08/1.8]`. More generally, there are `broadcasting` rules, but here it is a simple pairing of the values.